# Is .rdlx file is same as .rdl report file

Tags: sql-server, database, coldfusion

I am searching .rdl file. Once I start the worker process pdf is generating in our product. I have an .rdlx file in worker process folder if I open that it is showing xml format, but the report built in SSRS rdl file.
Is .rdlx file is the same as .rdl file.

Comment: `rdl` files are XML too. Have you had a [Search](https://www.google.com/search?&q=rdlx+file) of what an `rdlx` file is? The first result looks pretty informative.

Comment: RDLX file is a Power View Report Document. Power View is a feature of
 Microsoft Excel 2013, and is part of the Microsoft SQL Server 2012
Reporting Services add-in for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 and
 2013 Enterprise Editions. RDL file is an XML file that are used by the Reporting Service reports

Comment: @Larnu - I searched via google, and also using your link..  This SO is the first result.  In general, when a user asks a question, not taking the time to actually answer the question but adding commentary asking if they searched is not helpful at all, and it lacks the foresight that this question will be searched for and found by others.

Comment: This first result I get (this question is the 3rd result), @ttugates ,  is [RDLX File Extension](https://fileinfo.com/extension/rdlx). And yes, research is an expectation when posting on [so]; always has been, always will be.

Comment: I am avail to chat, but in the unedited OP, the user stated they searched. And so did I.  And the answer you provide in the link, happens to not answer the question directly.  I am seeing this file created by Grapecity Active Reports.